# A command to get currently installed versions of those listed with ">=" in requirements file (PIP) using grep/xargs

Tags: grep, python, xargs, pip

I have a `requirements.txt` file with versions listed e.g.

```
# requirements.txt
channels==2.4.0
colorama>=0.2.3
daphne==2.5.0
django-q>=1.1.4
```

For versions with `==` PIP installs that exact version but for those with `>=` it installs the highest it can based on other packages. I would like to save the installed version of all packages with `>=` in a new file (or if possible directly overwrite the ones in the original file), so for example the result could be:

```
# requirements_updates.txt
channels==2.4.0
colorama==0.4.3
daphne==2.5.0
django-q==1.3.4
```

I've tried stuff like
`cat requirements.txt | grep -Po ".*?(?=>=)" | xargs -I "python -m pip freeze | grep %" | grep -Po "(?<===).*?(?=$)"` during testing (and you should probably ignore that) but it stops producing output after multiple pipes, and it also doesn't take into account packages with `==` which should be copied blindly.
I prefer a command over a script so it is easy to share and use in already running Docker containers.

Comment: That `cat | grep | xargs` is a *script*. It's code in the shell language. If you can run that *command* / *script* in your "docker container", there shouldn't be anything stopping you from running any other *script* / *command*, whether they're written on one line or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
python -m pip freeze |
  awk '!x              {v[$1] = $2; next}
       NF>1 && $1 in v {$0 = $1"=="v[$1]}
                       {print}
      ' FS='==' - x=1 FS='>=' requirements.txt
```